# Other meanings of でしょう besides "probably"

Tags: meaning

でしょう can usually be understood to mean "probably." But does it sometimes mean the same thing as ですね? What other meanings can it have? Can it mean "you know?"

Comment: I've never heard it mean "probably".

Comment: Well it doesn't mean that exactly, but the English sentence usually has that word in it when translated.

Comment: In beginning language classes, it is often taught as "probably", as in the example: 雨が降るでしょう = It might/will probably rain.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Aside from the meaning of "probably", I've heard でしょう (だろう) used in the following manners:

1. In polite speech, でしょうか can replace ですか. でしょうか sounds "softer" and a little less direct:

   > この色【いろ】はいかがですか。 How about this color?
   >
   > この色【いろ】はいかが**でしょう**か。 How about this color? (slightly more polite)
   >
   > ちょっと分【わ】かりにくいですかね。 Do you suppose it's somewhat hard to follow?
   >
   > ちょっと分【わ】かりにくい**でしょう**かね。 Do you suppose it's somewhat hard to follow? (slightly more polite)
2. でしょう and だろう can be used like ね to form tag questions, primarily when the speaker knows something to be true and is using it to prove a point to or convince the listener of some fact. This use of でしょう often has a rising intonation:

   > で、帰【かえ】ったときに携帯【けいたい】はかばんに入【はい】ってなかった**だろう**？ So when you got back, your cell wasn't in your bag, right?
   >
   > 言【い】った**でしょう**？明日【あした】、東京【とうきょう】に行【い】くって。 I told you, didn't I? That I'd be going to Tokyo tomorrow.

   The question particle か is omitted in this use. In my experience, you're more likely to find だろう being used by men and でしょう by women here, but the split is not well defined, as both are fairly gender-neutral.

Comment: In the second sense, でしょう/だろう seem to be more analogous to よね than simply ね, e. g. 言ったでしょう seems to be closer to 言ったよね than simply 言ったね. Also, it may be worthwhile to mention contractions such as 言ったろ.

Comment: @Derek btw does でしょう means "probably" in the sense of たぶん ? or is it simply just a polite way of saying i'm certain (compared to です) ?

Comment: @Pacerier: That use of でしょう is for when you're fairly (70-90% or so?) certain something is true. It's often paired with たぶん or きっと, but these two can be paired with です as well. As far as the level of certainty, でしょう ranks above (more certain) than かもしれない and below です. So if you have plans to go to Tokyo tomorrow, you could say 明日の今ごろ、東京にいるでしょう。 ("Come this time tomorrow, I'll [almost certainly] be in Tokyo."). でしょう is better than います here because although something (very unlikely) might happen along the way, it's still almost a fact that you'll reach Tokyo.

Comment: @Derek heys btw just in case i've misunderstood it, do you mean that it is in this order: きっと, です, でしょう, たぶん, かもしれない (from certain to uncertain) ?

Comment: @Pacerier: きっと and たぶん shouldn't be in that list, since they're adverbs (like かならず and おそらく), but the rest of the list is correct.

Comment: @Derek oh ok, actually i was trying to do a comparison with the usage of たぶん and でしょう but i can see how they can't be compared. What about if we compare these 2 sentences: A) (trying to predict opponent's card) たぶん５だ。 B) 5でしょう。。 (dropping intonation.. i presume). will A indicate more "sureness" (as per the speaker) that the card is a 5 or will B indicate more sureness?

Comment: @Pacerier: For that example, I would say でしょう shows more confidence than たぶん～だ. But this is only how it feels to me, and if you ask native speakers I bet you'll get a range of different opinions.

Answer (score 7):

There is another slightly different use that takes some getting used to. Weather reporters frequently use でしょう to indicate likely weather:

明日の朝から雨がふるでしょう。

At first it always seemed like they were asking me for confirmation:)

To agree with previous posters, ですね　and でしょう are pretty different. The former is sort of a neutral comment, but can imply a question, whereas the latter is more implicitly asking for some kind of confirmation.

味が変ですね。-This tastes odd (wouldn't you agree?)
味が変でしょう。 - Doesn't this taste odd?

Answer (score 4):

でしょう is like です, but with less certainty.  It's used when someone is pretty sure something is that way, but not entirely.

So yes, it's a bit like 'probably', but that's not actually what it means.

It's often used when someone wants to see if someone else agrees with them before committing to it, too.

Comment: So how is that different from ですね? It's almost the same thing, right?

Comment: I would say they're close, but ですね is more looking for agreement after deciding, where でしょう is hedging your bets by not deciding absolutely until you see the opinion of those around you.

Comment: i thought でしょう was the more formal version of です

Comment: It's more polite than です but であります is the polite copula.

Comment: @Mark isn't でしょう the formal version of だろう ?

Comment: @William is the intonation of でしょう (probably) dropping?

Comment: @pacerier: ah you are right about だろう... had a momentary brain fart on this one.