# What does '........でしょう' mean?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I am not good at using '...でしょう', and do not fully understand its meaning and usage. For example:

> 彼はｱﾒﾘｶへ行くんでしょう
>
> そのことをわからないんでしょう

Such sentences always make me confused. Could you explain it for me?

Answer (score 2):

でしょう is polite version of だろう. That means probably, displaying conjecture.

> 彼女は(多分)彼の恋人だろう.
>   She is probably his girlfriend.

Comment: It might be more accurate to say 'polite' rather than 'formal'.  The former is the difference between だ and です, while the latter is the difference between だ and である.

Comment: @snailplane I think it's slightly more muddled than that; you'll see だ in formal writing, but never である in informal contexts - except as a joke, of course.

Comment: ^ つまり「である」は通常 formal のみですが「だ」は casual のみでなく formal にも使えるということですから、なおさら snail さんの言う通り「でしょう」(「です」+助動詞「う・よう」) は「だろう」(「だ」+「う・よう」) の formal version と言うよりも polite version と言った方が正確だ、ということになると思います・・・

Answer (score 1):

[でしょう](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86) is a more polite form of [だろう](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86) which is broadly used to suggest a speaker's guess and supposition. That means the speaker is not sure about it.

For example:

> これは[本物]{ほんもの}のダイヤでしょう. (I am not sure about it but) This is **probably** a real diamond.

Answer (score 0):

Related:　[Other meanings of でしょう besides "probably"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1558/other-meanings-of-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%97%e3%82%87%e3%81%86-besides-probably)

It's likely the 2nd usage of でしょう similar in meaning to ね but it depends on the context but could also be the first, showing uncertainty on the side of the speaker.

> 彼はｱﾒﾘｶへ行くんでしょう

He's going to the states, right?

> そのことをわからないんでしょう

You don't get it, do you?

Comment: でしょう is different from ね in the point that the former points out what the listener is not really aware of while the latter doesn't.