# What does "deshyo" alone mean as a response?

Tags: interjections, casual

When I tell someone something and in response I get only "deshyo?!" or "deshyo!", what does this imply? "I've told you so", "That must be so"?

Comment: Possible duplicate.   https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/39688/what-does-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86-mean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does '........でしょう' mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/39688/what-does-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%97%e3%82%87%e3%81%86-mean)

Comment: I contend the duplicate claim. This question asks for でしょう when used alone. The answers to the other questions use でしょう as part of the sentence.

Comment: I think when a question is bumped to the homepage for having a limited answer, the message should include a specific request for new answers. As it stands now, people reading the "bumped to homepage" message may simply choose to vote on the answer given, rather than try to provide a better one.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on context, it could mean those things you said, but the simplest way to parse deshou is "right?" or "I know, right?"

(specifically in response to something you've just said, as mentioned in your question)